# Recibir url cake php

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

quiero saber como hacer lo siguiente:

Cuando la pagina venga desde google, quiero cambiar de pagina si la pagina es encontrada desde el buscador de google, y que muestre otra si es ingresada manualmente la url

Comment: no es para nada clara tu pregunta

Comment: Hola Andrés, podrías mostrarnos que has intentado?

Comment: No, es que no tengo ni idea de como se hace eso y me lo estan pidiendo.

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado amplia, carece de una descripción de los buscado/investigado y no es clara. Además se incluyen varias etiquetas pero no se mencionan los tópicos correspondientes en el cuerpo de la pregunta. Si no lo has hecho aún por favor revisa [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes comprobar el parámetro HTTP_REFERER:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], "google")!==false) {
    echo "Has llegado desde google";
} else {
    echo "Has llegado de otra manera";
}
```

Comment: Por ahora creo que si funciona, pero no puedo estar seguro hasta no publicar la pagina. ps aun no he probado cuando viene desde google, solo tengo una duda mas, se puede saber como fue la búsqueda desde google, lo que quiero decir es saber con que palabras de búsqueda dio con mi pagina.

Comment: Si la persona que ha buscado en google utiliza https (actualmente es lo habitual casi siempre) no se puede saber, porque esa información la oculta google. Si no es así, sí que podrías saberlo, la búsqueda exacta vendría en esa misma variable $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], verías algo asi: http://www.google.com?q=la-frase-exacta-de-busqueda-aqui.